# Making a dual boot scenario with Windows, getting unusual db error

Tags: linux, debian, installation, nvidia

over the last few days I've been mulling over the idea of getting Debian on my desktop which has had windows on it for the longest.  I had thought this would be a pretty easy thing to do, I plugged in another SATA drive for it to be installed on, flashed the USB with the latest ISO but received a error after pressing either install option.

`Error reading db var attributes: 0x0000000000000007`

In the past I had never had issues installing Debian but that was also on my old laptop.  In my desktop I do have a nvidia card and have tried doing the `nomodeset` option after `quiet` as well as multiple other options people have recommended that I can't recall or find again.  Now mind you the times I was attempting these fixes was when I was not using the UEFI installer but still didn't help the UEFI when I switched to it.  It should also be noted I don't get any error message with the BIOS installer instead just a blackscreen.  Ive tried looking around for how to solve this error but no one else seems to have had this yet.

Let me know if any other information may be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Try removing the `quiet` option; you may have a different problem that you can't see because of it.

Comment: I have and no real error appears to my eye, it initializes the storage devices then stops there after all are initialized.